# Stripe.net: How can I determine if a customer's default source is chargeable

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

The Stripe API has a `source` object that has a `status` field that tells you whether the payment instrument is chargeable or not.

However, in Stripe.net, all of the `Source`-related properties on the Customer object are of type `StripeCard`, which does not have any `Status` property. In fact, I can't see any way to retrieve a `Source` object in Stripe.net.

I'd like to be able to know whether a customer has a chargeable (not expired, etc) payment instrument hooked up to their account. How can I do this?

Also, does Stripe.net not allow manipulation of non-card payment instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe.net is a third-party library which means it wasn't built by Stripe. They haven't added support for `Sources` just yet which is why you're not seeing this. You can either make your own pull-request for this or report the issue on their [github repo](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/issues)

Separately, though, you don't need to implement any of this at the moment. Cards and Bank Accounts are always chargeable by default. This `status` field is new and has been added for other sources such as Bitcoin Receivers but this isn't fully supported by Stripe officially just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say that cards are always chargeable, does that mean that if a card becomes unchargeable for some reason (customer cancels the card separately, card expires, etc), when I retrieve the Customer object, it won't have the unable card on it? The basic problem I'm trying to solve is to know whether I need to ask my users to update their cards when I show them their account details.

Comment: That's correct, the `status` wouldn't change on the card. The reason is that the bank can reject a charge but accept another later too. Declines are not just "always no" or "always yes". The only to know if you can charge a card is to, well, charge that card and see what the bank says. If it fails you'd ask your customer to update his card details.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you're saying that Stripe doesn't automatically perform some kind of confirmation that previously associated cards are still valid. Once the card is on the customer object, it's just static data and it's my responsibility to see if it works and take appropriate action if it doesn't. Please let me know if I've misunderstood. I'm marking your reply as the answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @BrianRak that's correct, it's up to you. Even expired cards can work sometimes depending on the bank so on Stripe's end they keep the card saved and you decide when to attempt it on your end.